# Outlook 2003 -> Outlook 2010 Migration

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2003

I am manually upgrading from 2003 to 2010. I backed up my old Windows XP installation using VMWare vCenter, so I have the old machine in a VM.

The new install is XP with Office 2010. I have managed to import the old .pst file, but I had to create the e-mail account manually. Outlook has helpfully created a new .pst file now by the same name as the e-mail account, but I want to carry on using the old .pst file. How can I change the .pst file associated with the e-mail account?

Some screenshot here: http://www.hosting.com/support/microsoft-outlook-2010-/change-the-data-file-for-saving-in-outlook-2010

Looked promising but that button is **not** present for me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious:  why do you want to keep using the old .pst file?  Each version of Outlook has implemented tweaks to the pst format, which makes it more stable and robust than ever before.  I strongly recommend simply recreating your account in Outlook 2010, and then importing the contents of your old pst file into the new account.

Comment: Try this page: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/backup-config/moving-outlook-to-a-new-computer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a new outlook profile, and then import your old PST file using these instructions:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/office-outlook-2010-import-and-export/

In general, if you create a new profile, I believe you will need to manually insert the following data:

1. Email server information (POP3, IMAP, and/or SMTP information).  Usually, ISP and internet mail services post how-to's on setting this up.  Google is your friend in this case.  For example, for Gmail, you might want to search "Gmail Outlook 2010 setup."
2. Username/passowrd information.  If you don't know this, then you should contact your email provider.
3. Rules for organizing email.  These will probably need to be recreated.
4. Signatures.  Again, must be recreated.
5. Custom dictionaries and white/black lists for junk email.